# Xcode 8.3.2 cannot find CocoaAsyncSocket.h

Tags: objective-c, swift3, xcode8, multicast, ipv4

I'm an old-school c/c++ programmer new to the Xcode IDE, tasked with creating an app for iOS that can receive data from an IPv4 multicast address.  Since Swift 3 doesn't have an API for joining to a multicast address or binding to a port, I need to embed Objective-C code in the Swift code.

I have found a number of ways to do it with an asynch UDP socket, but when I reference either CocoaAsyncSocket.h (or GCDAsyncUdpSocket.h), I get an error "Module 'CocoaAsyncSocket' not found." Indeed, if I do a file search, I come up dry.

I don't see that Objective-C or its libraries can be downloaded from Apple, and they didn't come along when I downloaded Xcode 8.3.2, nor can I locate an Open Source version.  Can anyone provide some pointers?  Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html CocoaAsyncSocket is most probably third party library. from Swift it is very easy to use any C API, as you did as old-school c programmer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)

[UDP Server and Client in Swift](https://www.stansidel.com/2016/02/udp-server-and-client-in-swift/)

[Using the BlueSocket framework to create an echo server](http://masteringswift.blogspot.sk/2017/01/using-bluesocket-framework-to-create.html)

[Multi-Client echo server with the BlueSocket framework and libdispatch](http://masteringswift.blogspot.sk/2017/01/multi-client-echo-server-with.html)

[BlueSocket](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSocket) pure Swift ...

Minimalistic Multi-Client [EchoSerwer](https://gist.github.com/op183/0f466bfaa195ccb0a9e73d5d453a0a32) written in Swift (no external framework required)

[image]

Minimalistic [Echo UDP Server](https://gist.github.com/op183/047500a2d982fd8840be8bc00abb9450) written in Swift (no external framework required)

[image]